# Looping through curve_fit, how to skip empty data?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am looping through 4 3D arrays to obtain a ydata from them and pass it into a curve_fit function. I am plotting the log of the data and I get a lot of nan and inf. I used a mask to filter the ydata set but then I face an error due to empty data. How can I pass such empty data set.

my code is

```
xdata_1000 = np.array([50,300,600,1000])

for i in range(n):
    for r in range(d):
        for c in range(d):
            b50_value = round(b50_data[i,r,c],4)
            b300_value = round(b300_data[i,r,c],4)
            b600_value = round(b600_data[i,r,c],4)
            b1000_value = round(b1000_data[i,r,c],4)

            ydata_fit1 = np.array([b50_value, b300_value, b600_value, b1000_value])
            ydata_fit1 = np.log(ydata_fit1 / ydata_fit1[0])
            index1 = ~np.isnan(ydata_fit1)

            def fit(x,a_slope,b_intercept):
                return a_slope * x + b_intercept


            popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(fit, xdata_1000, ydata_fit1[index1])
            popt1[0] = popt1[0] * 1000
            ADC_50_300_600_1000[i,r,c] = popt1[0]
```

Without the mask I get

```
[nan nan nan nan]
```

While with it the data is empty

```
[]
```

Comment: Would you please add the missing import statements to your code? Also variables such as "n" are undefined.

Comment: If the *data itself* has inf and nan values, you can filter those out with numpy.isfinite().